# VBA - Bring latest Excel file path from a folder

Tags: excel, vba

We have a series of individual folders for each country we work with. The sub folders all follow the same structure. I need to check for the most recent file saved with the naming containing the word "WIP". I tried many ways, but it always sorted half of my needs.

When I add "*WIP*.xls*" to the filename it only returns the first file it finds. When I use it like "*.xls*" it returns all files BUT the first one.

I only need the full path of the latest file saved with the work "WIP" in it.

This is the code I've working on:

```
'Go through Columns, check Country and update formulas
    Do While Cells(StartRow, Counter).Value <> Empty
        CurrentCountry = Cells(StartRow, Counter)
        FullPath = FixedFolderPath & CurrentYear & "\" & CurrentCountry & "\" & CurrentMonthPath
        Debug.Print CurrentCountry
        
        '-----------------------------------
        'Checking the most recent WIP wile

        'With this line I get the 1st file only
        Filename = Dir(FullPath & "*.xls*", vbNormal)

        'With this structure I get them all BUT the first file
        Do While Filename <> ""
            Filename = Dir
            Debug.Print Filename
        Loop

        Counter = Counter + 1
        Filename = ""
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used this one to find the most recent file which should also work for your needs:

```
Function NewestFile(Path As String, Optional FileSpec As String)
    Dim FileName As String, MostRecentFile As String
    Dim MostRecentDate As Date
    
    'Specify the file type, if any
    If IsMissing(FileSpec) Then
        'Dim FileSpec As String Not needed I guess, even when it's optional?
        FileSpec = "*.txt" 'I need to work with a lot of txt files
    End If
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
    
    FileName = Dir(Path & FileSpec)
    
    If FileName <> "" Then
        MostRecentFile = FileName
        MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Path & FileName)
        Do While FileName <> ""
            If FileDateTime(Path & FileName) > MostRecentDate Then
                 MostRecentFile = FileName
                 MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Path & FileName)
            End If
            FileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
    
    NewestFile = MostRecentFile

End Function
```

Used in your example would be something like this:

```
    Dim lastFile As String
    If FileName <> "" Then 'or check if NewestFile <> "" after letting the function run
        lastFile = NewestFile(FullPath, "*WIP*.xlsx")
    End If
```

Hope that works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting the Filename first.

```
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Debug.Print Filename
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
```

Comment: Ah, I cannot believe it ... that was it ... Now I have to add the latest file test, but at least all the files are returning to the search. Thank you ! =)